# CSS "mask" property does not work properly on Chrome

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, google-chrome

I've created a custom progress bar component in React that uses a gradient background. To achieve this effect, I'm using the CSS mask property. The progress bar works perfectly in Firefox, but I'm encountering an issue in Chrome.

The mask doesn't seem to apply correctly on Chrome until I force a rerender by resizing the browser or unchecking and checking the mask property again.

The problem does not happen here in stack overflow, only on the code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/progress-bar-7czghg

```js
    function increaseWidthUntil100Percent(element, currentWidth = 0) {
      if (currentWidth < 100) {
        const newWidth = currentWidth + 5;
        element.style.width = `${newWidth}%`;

        setTimeout(() => {
          increaseWidthUntil100Percent(element, newWidth);
        }, 1000);
      }
    }

    const myDiv = document.getElementById('bar');
    increaseWidthUntil100Percent(myDiv);
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  height: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  background-color: #c0c6df;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.progress-bar > .progress-bar__bar::before {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 3rem;
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(209, 107, 165, 1) 0%,
    rgba(132, 166, 228, 1) 50%,
    rgba(1, 22, 42, 1) 100%
  );
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.progress-bar > .progress-bar__bar {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
  mask: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div id="bar" style="width: 0" class="progress-bar__bar"></div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```css
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

to `.progress-bar__bar` should do the trick. No idea why it works after you resize the window. I would have thought it shouldn't.

Comment: This solution stretches the progress bar gradient, whereas in the initial solution, it reveals the background accordingly to the mask width.

Comment: You're right, @Eros, didn't notice that. You might want to report it to Chrome. As a side note, giving `percentage` an initial value of `0.01` seems to fix it, too. Again, I have no idea what's causing this. I'd be quite curious to find out. Please share the link to the Chromium bug report, once you open it.

Comment: What's even funnier is that initial `percentage` values below `0.0027` don't seem to trigger the "fix". Probably related to sub-pixel rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will solve your issue but here is a different idea using `clip-path` and CSS variables

```js
function increaseWidthUntil100Percent(element, currentWidth = 0) {
      if (currentWidth < 100) {
        const newWidth = currentWidth + 5;
        element.style.setProperty('--w',`${newWidth}%`);

        setTimeout(() => {
          increaseWidthUntil100Percent(element, newWidth);
        }, 1000);
      }
    }

    const myDiv = document.getElementById('bar');
    increaseWidthUntil100Percent(myDiv);
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  height: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  background-color: #c0c6df;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  display: grid;
}

.progress-bar > .progress-bar__bar {
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(209, 107, 165, 1) 0%,
    rgba(132, 166, 228, 1) 50%,
    rgba(1, 22, 42, 1) 100%
  );
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  clip-path:inset(0 calc(100% - var(--w,0%)) 0 0 round 3rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div id="bar" class="progress-bar__bar"></div>
</div>
```